# Java: Can't find symbol

Tags: java, tostring, nan

In Javadoc it was written that :

> public static String toString(double d)
>
> > Returns a string representation of the double argument. All characters mentioned below are ASCII characters.
>
> If the argument is NaN, the result is the string "NaN".

But when I am compiling below code it is giving error: Cant find symbol NaN

```
String intStr2 =Double.toString(NaN);
```

Comment: What's the value of `infinity`?

Comment: Surely if the compiler complains about symbol NaN, the error is on code that mentions NaN? Are you sure the error is on that line? Show us more code!

Comment: `Cant find symbol NaN` means you have a reference for a variable called `NaN` which you have not declared.

Comment: I editted that NaN should mean that of double type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since NaN is not defined, it throws a compilation error, use the following to overcome the same,

```
String intStr2 = Double.toString(Double.NaN);
```

Comment: @Satish    String intStr2 =Double.toString(Double.infinity); 
  String intStr2 =Double.toString(Double.Infinity);   Again giving same error

Comment: @Ronaldo7 there is nothing called Double.infinity or Double.Infinity that's why you are getting the error. If you want to check the infinity, then use the following line, Double.toString(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

Comment: Please refer to the following Oracle documentation to know what is available - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

`Double.NaN` is defined in [`Double.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.0NaN) as (ref jdk8)

```
/**
 * A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type
 * {@code double}. It is equivalent to the value returned by
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)}.
 */
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

And it is well converted in String "NaN"

```
String intStr2 =Double.toString(Double.NaN); 
System.out.println(intStr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error NaN is "Not a Number". You'd have to define it first.

```
String intStr2 = Double.toString(Double.NAN);
```

You'd be able to throw it in print and it should print. For infinity, you'd have to use(Positive and negative, interchangeable.)

```
String intStr2 = Double.toString(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
System.out.print(intStr2);
```

Should print out Infinity